# Why job postings always looking for "rockstars?"

Tags: career-development

I have noticed a recent trend in requesting programmers who are *rockstars*.  I get it, they're looking for someone who is really good at what they do.  But why (pray) make the reference to a rockstar?

Do these companies really want these traits as a real rockstar?

- [Party all night and wake up to take care of quick business in the morning](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rockstar)?
- Substance abuse,
- Narcissism with celebrity,
- Compensation well exceeding their management,
- Excellent at putting on a short-lived show,
- Entertainment instead of value,
- 1 hit (project) wonders or single-genre performers,
- Et cetera

What is wrong with *Senior* or *Principal* Software Engineer who has an established and proven passion for the business?  Rather do we mean quite the opposite, someone who:

- rolls up the sleeves and gets to work,
- takes appropriate direction and helps influence teams,
- programs in lessons' learned and proper practices,
- provides timely communication to the whole team,
- can code and understand multiple languages,
- understands the science and theory behind computation,

Is there a trend to diversify the software engineering ranks?  **How many software rockstars can you hire before your band starts breaking up?**

Sure, there are lots of folks doing this stuff on their own, maybe even a rare few who do coding for show, but I wager the majority is for business.  I don't see ads for rockstar accountants, or rockstar machinists, or rockstart CFOs.  What makes the software programmer and their hiring departments lean towards this kind of job title?

Comment: _Where_ are you seeing this?

Comment: @Jonathan Khoo - I see it on Dice sometimes. (there are 46 results for "rockstar" right now)

Comment: @Jonathan Khoo - Even within this community: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=rockstar

Comment: FWIW I've never seen an ad posting looking for a "rockstar"... at least not until now, when @Xepoch posted that link...

Comment: I've seen a few ads asking for "rockstars"...

Comment: +1. I started writing a question a lot like this a week or two ago, but got a call and didn't get a chance to finish. The title I came up with was more like "is being called a rockstar a compliment or an insult?" though...

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, I think that's a valid question too = do you put "rockstar" on your résumé?

Comment: @Xepoch: I never have, but maybe I should try...

Comment: Hahahaha! Joel Spolsky has some explaining to do. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/searchResults.html?cx=partner-pub-7553644598686111:bl4i7p-y0o5&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&q=rock%20stars&sa=Search&siteurl=joelonsoftware.com%252F

Comment: I've seen a similar trend looking for 'ninjas' in their field. seems especially prevalent in the web design / development fields.

Comment: Maybe they're trying to poach staff at a certain [games publisher](http://www.rockstargames.com/)?

Comment: The other one is "Ninja". Some companies are starting to fight back and make fun of this by advertising for "Jazz" or "Pirate" programmers. I read a cool blog post a while ago, where someone explained why they'd much prefer to be a jazz programmer than a rockstar. Worth a read.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: "Ninja" programmers? What is that, really? Someone who sneaks into the office, fixes a bug, commits it through someone else's account and sneaks back out again?

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: http://deadprogrammersociety.blogspot.com/2007/05/i-would-rather-be-jazz-programmer.html  Jazz programmers: Their programs start off pretty normally but quickly descend into experimental, ad-libbed craziness that nobody else understands.  They know the theory of programming inside-out but a lot of what they do doesn't quite work.

Comment: "Rockstar" just means REALLY GOOD programmer. Who doesn't want a really good programmer, other than the people who aren't willing to pay for it? No one wants an "okay" programmer or a "terrible" programmer.

Comment: "Welcome to Google, where we are ALL rockstars. That's the whiskey fountain, over there is the coke-bar, and down the hall and to the left is the Groupie Room."

Comment: I'd like to be a ninja programmer.  I'd never show up for work, and when people asked questions about why they never saw me I'd just say it was because of my awesome ninja skills.

Comment: @AndrewLatham You'd need to both never show up for work and do the best work out of anybody there for it to be convincing.

Comment: Some questions are best answered with a piece of music. http://youtu.be/9QS0q3mGPGg

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The term "rockstar" implies a certain amount of glamour, flash, sexiness, maybe even dangerousness, characteristics which really good programmers generally don't exhibit, but might wish they did.  I wouldn't take it too literally.  That is to say, it's a buzzword, and like many such, not particularly useful.

Comment: @user13645: The company expects a developer to display sexiness? You are hiring for coding right?

Comment: @Fanatic23: No, they expect the developer to _think_ he/she displays sexiness.  Whether the developer actually _does_ display sexiness is in the eye of the beholder.  Except in my case, where it's a reflection of objective reality (assuming that I get to define sexy for everyone else, of course).

Comment: I'm not sure about glamour but I can probably pull off flash, sexiness, and definitely dangerousness on a good day. I wouldn't really label myself a 'good' programmer though. Probably something more along the lines of 'striving to suck less every day'. :)

Comment: @Fanatic23 Is that your call stack, or are you just happy to see me?

Answer (score 19):

Because Rockstars will works for a lot less than a Principal Software Engineer.

Actually, I propose the creation of the title Chief of Software, for the guy who buil[t|ds] the software the company runs on. With lots of shares, a hefty salary in the $500K+ range, secretary, access to corporate retreat, jet, a badge that gets full access everywhere, a signature that can sign good million-dollar checks, a large office with conference table, 12 computers for himself, and an IT department that says "Yes Sir Right Away Sir" because they don't want to hear him say: "Meet me in my office with a VP from HR in ten minutes."

It's about time the marketing and finance boys learn who really runs the company.

Comment: Yeah, good luck with that.

Comment: I think that you over estimate your value.

Comment: I think that guy is called the CIO.

Comment: @Pemdas: You're saying the Marketing dude isn't over-estimating his value?

Comment: @Malvolio: You want to stay in the basement with your red stapler reinventing the wheel in c#4? Go ahead.

Comment: @Kirk: the CIO doesn't program--and if he did once, he certainly does not now.

Comment: @Christopher Mahan - The chief of construction for a skyscraper doesn't fasten screws, either.  That's 'grunt work'.

Comment: @Kirk: I rest my case.

Comment: But Christopher the guy described in your answer doesn't program either!  He runs the IT division.  You expect him to make the big decisions, plans and designs, & consult across the company on technology and integration, but then go back to his desk and hack through some PHP, or drag some ASP controls around?  I think he'd be very busy and have more important things to do than that!

Comment: Oh, there's nothing more important than programming well. And he most certainly won't be using PHP or ASP. This is why the top programmer needs to be treated like the top guy, because he is. He leaves, company's in trouble.

Comment: LOL that is the funniest thing I've read all day. up voted you for the comedy value. Besides people like the one @Christopher describes do exist, its just they are the creators of the facebooks and googles of the world. If you go work for someone else, theres this little thing called IP that gets in the way.

Comment: spoken like a true rockstar

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, OSS all the way.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at the [UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Rockstar%20Programmer) definitions. One defines a rockstar programmer as a weak technically but strong politicially (seems like what you're describing), and the other describes someone who is truly proficient.

I like the description on the second definition - it's like a guitar player who is beyond just good - thus rock star.

Interestingly, the first definition got more votes.

I agree, it's a stupid term, but it stuck. A good question (that I would like answer) is when this term was first used.

Comment: I suspect it may be a case of unintentional truth: the company really does want someone who is politically very good and if they can program too that's a bonus. So they advertise for a really good programmer, a rockstar. I am definitely not inclined to work for them, but if I saw the ad locally I might be tempted to apply and go along to the interview in a satirical manner (turn up looking and acting like Ozzy Osbourne)

Comment: I'd consider a rockstar programmer to be somebody like Steve Yegge, Linus Torvalds, Joel Spolsky, Scott Guthrie, etc... Guys who aren't only talented in their respective fields but they're sometimes working on the leading edge and willing to share their experiences (which could potentially draw a massive pool of talent). I can honestly say that I've read a lot of their stuff (or watched their videos, listened to podcasts) and I'd be excited to work with them if I had the chance. Most importantly, even without the audience, they'll still be successful because they're good at what they do.

Answer (score 8):

I first saw this term with Ruby.  There are several puns around the name of the language in that community.  (For instance calling packages "gems".)  Therefore I suspect that "rock star" started as another natural in joke, and then spread.

Comment: Interesting take.

Comment: what's next? Maybe developers with an interest in jewellery? :P

Comment: interesting, do you have any web sources to add to your answer? Your idea has merit.

Answer (score 7):

[Rock Star Engineers Debut in Intel's New Advertising Campaign That Focuses on the Future](http://www.fastcompany.com/blog/clay-dillow/culture-buffet/intel-shifts-focus-future-new-advertising-strategy)  would be the Intel ad that you may have missed that some companies may just blindly follow that lead.

Ever wonder if the reason why some companies put up such cheesy job ads is that they are trying to get people to apply?  Consider how whatever ad it is that had that term is something you tell a friend, "Could you believe this company wants..." rather than just not having that discussion and the information doesn't spread like a virus.

If you saw a job ad that put you to sleep, would you apply there?  Really?

Answer (score 6):

It seems like an attempt to invoke the image of someone with loads of talent and passion for what they do. At least in a extremely simplified, rosy-glasses connotation of "rockstar". That and possibly an attempt to make the company sound a lot cooler than it is.

Comment: yeah exactly, should be read as a flag for "Don't work here unless you want to catch the black plague for lolz"

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much every company out there is claiming to (and/or trying to) hire only people in the top 1 percentile of the professional population in their field.
Of course this is utterly impossible, as 99% of employees in the field cannot all be in the top 1 percent.

Some companies/headhunters just use different language to express that desire than do others.
Some call it rocket engineers, some call it rockstars, some are honest and just state openly that "we want only the best".

And all of them will then try to screw you over during contract negotiations and offer compensation that's not at all in line with what you'd expect the best in the industry to be paid.

Comment: "And all of them will then try to screw you over during contract negotiations and offer compensation that's not at all in line with what you'd expect the best in the industry to be paid." They probably have skewed ideas of what the 1% are. I'd wager that 70% of companies would take somebody in the top 30% just because *they* think they're getting somebody in the 1%.

Answer (score 3):

I think it means that the dress code is not the usual 'business' / 'smart office' but more rockstar specific, e.g. 'punk' / 'torn jeans'.  You have to wear muscle shirts and black jeans, have really trendy haircuts, and lots of tattoos.

If you work with C / C++ you're expected to wear spandex pants, loose tanktops and a headband (you aspire to be the Axl Rose of programming).

If you work with COBOL or Fortran then you should wear tie-died shirts and flared jeans, maybe have an afro or long hair.  Platform shoes optional, and you should enjoy smoking weed and dropping acid in your lunch hour.

Comment: uh, no. The term is merely indicative of the "we only want the top 1% of people to apply" attitude that's completely taken over the industry.
Typically there will be strict dresscodes in companies explicitly stating so, as they consider themselves elitist. 
Expect everyone to be expected to sit at their desks in a 3 piece suit and tie all day, every day.

Comment: Take me down to parenthesis city/where the notation's big-O for complexity/Oh won't you please take me home!

Comment: @jwenting you are correct. I think Kirk missed the point, or perhaps hasn't read any such job ads (possibly because he is in a secure job which he enjoys). on a side note I hope never to work at such a place. yucky.

Comment: I guess some programmers really do have no sense of humour - is it not completely obvious that this is a joke?

Answer (score 3):

Because they have an over inflated sense of the importance of their own products. Like celebrities who only get with other celebrities, some companies feel they need 'rockstar' developers. Just ego. A good solid team, well lead, with varying skills will do better than a couple of 'rockstars'.

Answer (score 2):

I always see stuff about Rockstar DBAs and such....but like many others say I think it's just a flashy word. Or maybe it makes the company hiring looks cool...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe they want someone from [Band on the Runtime](http://weblogs.asp.net/cfranklin/archive/2005/04/17/402346.aspx).

"Band on the runtime" was made up of a few famous developers in the .Net world, with musical talent too, who played gigs at programming conferences. "Rockstar developer" is a silly term, so a joke fits here.

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and why do you recommend it as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: @gnat It's a joke. "Band on the runtime" was made up of a few famous developers in the .Net world, with musical talent too, who played gigs at programming conferences. "Rockstar developer" is a silly term, so a (cw) joke is a reasonable answer. It's a phrase that shouldn't be taken literally.

Answer (score 1):

It's a psychological trick. **Who doesn't want to be a rockstar?**

Comment: It's antiproductive. A true "rockstar" would never consider himself to be one and won't apply. Only those will who are clueless.

Comment: ^ True hipsters, mahn!

Answer (score 1):

I blame Intel & Microsoft for this term. They started using it heavily in their advertising material awhile back, and ever since Recruiters have thought it was a pseudo technical term for geek.

But yeah, if they need a Rockstar, or a ninja or any other crappy keyword based role, they are basically asking for a slave that will code non stop for 14 hours a day, go non stop for 48 hour periods during the final production release schedule, as well as being expected to mentor and train less experienced staff.

The irony is that there are still alot of programmers out there that at least have the narcism bit in common with a Rockstar, in that they see it as their duty to work insane hours to prove how hardcore they are. Mores the pity all it does is make the rest of us look bad, because we are smart and don't want to ruin our health doing stupid work practises.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that at least part of the times the main reason is to make the position appear more glamorous to the potential programmer.

The same holds for some interview questions that are more challenging from the day to day work in those places, and are mainly used to make the position appear interesting

Answer (score 0):

I think it's mostly a way to represent the tone or environment of the company. Generally (or, at least, originally) the places that advertised for "rockstar programmers" are startups. They want to advertise that they aren't your usual button-down-and-khakis corporate cubicle farm, but something *fun*. (The cynical side of me says that they push their laid-back side as a perk to make up for less in the way of compensation, but I digress.) In effect, it's a way of saying "stodgy suit-and-ties need not apply". Often startups are not only looking for good programmers, but someone who meshes well with the environment (since startups are so small) and is passionate about the product (they're not just looking for a paycheck). And rockstars are cool, y'know?

Answer (score 0):

Rock symbolises individuality, rebellion against status quo, preconceived ideas about the world order and established authority. It is associated with independent mindedness, feeling strongly about own ideas and convictions, determination. And being a star simply means that the person is damn good at what they do. Rockstars are able to ignite with energy and passion everyone around them.

It's easy to see why technology companies willing to build things that were never built or even deemed possible before try to attract candidates with these qualities.

The exact opposite would be someone trying to blend in, a person accepting established rules, constraints and conventional wisdoms. Treating the job as something that "pays the bills" and seeking to be told what to do. Always looking for a compromise and being worried about upsetting the existing order, being fairly average at what they do and lacking any visible energy or passion to share with others. A somewhat degrading industry term would be "a coding monkey".

I believe that the term rockstar as referring to an intellectual worker was first introduced into programming culture by T. Lister and T. DeMarco in Peopleware, but I might be wrong. Then it was further popularised by J. Spolsky in his essays on software development.

Comment: +1 for the historical paragraph (please add reference?) but -1 for thinking that programmers should betray the established methodologies of those for whom they work?